# How to combine conditional operator in NoRM driver for MongoDB

Tags: .net, mongodb, norm, nosql

In mongo native api it is possible to do following:

db.collection.find({ "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );    // value1 < field < value

How could I achieve the same with NoRM

Best regards,
Dmitry Egorov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this support to the repo, also Adam added LINQ support to do the following..

```
collection.Find({"field" : Q.GreaterThan(value1).And(Q.GreaterThan(value2))});
```